# How to find out to which window the focus was passed on for a "WindowDeactivate" event?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

By installing an event filter, it is possible to see if a window has been activated/deactivated ([`QtCore.QEvent.WindowActivate`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html), [`QtCore.QEvent.WindowDeactivate`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html)).

```
class SomeWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget, object):
    # ...
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.installEventFilter(self)
        # ...

    def eventFilter(self, object, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.WindowDeactivate:
            print('Window was deactivated.')
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.WindowActivate:
            print('Window was activated.')
```

Is it possible to find out A) to which other window (of the same application) the focus was passed on, and B) whether the entire application was inactivated (that is: none of the windows is active)?

I wish the solution to be "minimal invasive" in that sense that I don't have to install event filters in all of my candidate windows. Is it possible to spy out other windows from within the current widget?

I'm interested in this information because I would like to capture some usage metrics for my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to monitor the status of the windows you can use the notify method of QApplication:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Application(QtWidgets.QApplication):
    def notify(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.WindowDeactivate:
            print("{} was deactivated:".format(obj))
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.WindowActivate:
            print("{} was activated.".format(obj))
        return super().notify(obj, event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = Application(sys.argv)
    windows = []
    for _ in range(3):
        w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        w.show()
        windows.append(w)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Using the previous method I have implemented a signal that sends the activated window with the function QApplication::activeWindow():

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Application(QtWidgets.QApplication):
    activateChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtWidgets.QWidget)

    def __init__(self, l):
        super().__init__(l)
        self._window_activate = None

    def notify(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.WindowDeactivate:
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.on_timeout)
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.WindowActivate:
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.on_timeout)
        return super().notify(obj, event)

    def on_timeout(self):
        if self._window_activate != QtWidgets.QApplication.activeWindow():
            self._window_activate = QtWidgets.QApplication.activeWindow()
            self.activateChanged.emit(self._window_activate)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = Application(sys.argv)
    app.activateChanged.connect(print)
    windows = []
    for _ in range(5):
        w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        w.show()
        windows.append(w)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```